# Sum a series n^n for values 1 through n with no overflow? Only last digits of answer needed

Tags: java, biginteger

I want to write a Java program that sums all the integers n^n from 1 through n. I only need the last 10 digits of this number, but the values given for n exceed 800.

I have already written a basic java program to calculate this, and it works fine for n < 16. But it obviously doesn't deal with such large numbers. I am wondering if there is a way to just gather the last 10 digits of a number that would normally overflow a long, and if so, what that method or technique might be.

I have no code to show, just because the code I wrote already is exactly what you'd expect. A for loop that runs i*i while i<=n and a counter that sums each iteration with the one before. It works. I just don't know how to approach the problem for bigger numbers, and need guidance.

Around n=16, the number overflows a long, and returns negative values. Will BigInteger help with this, or is that still too small a data type? Or could someone point me towards a technique for gathering the last 10 digits of a massive number? I could store it in an array and then sum them up if I could just get that far.

Anyhow, I don't expect a finished piece of code, but maybe some suggestions as to how I could look at this problem anew? Some techniques my n00b self is missing?

Thank you!

Comment: you don't need to use biginteger at all, if you do all calculations the modulus you are given, all the arithmetic operations you need are in the precision you need.  Just use `long` values, and at each operation reduce mod `N`.  There's a _fast exponentiation_ algorithm described, to do exponentiation faster than just multiplying by the base `N` times.

Answer (score 2):

> sums all the integers n^n from 1 through n. I only need the last 10 digits of this number

If you only need last 10 digits, that means you need `sum % 10¹⁰`.

The sum is `1¹ + 2² + 3³ + ... nⁿ`.

According to [equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Equivalences) rules:

> `(a + b) % n = [(a % n) + (b % n)] % n`

So you need to calculate `iⁱ % 10¹⁰`, for i=1 to n, sum them, and perform a last modulus on that sum.

According to the [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) article on Wikipedia, there are efficient ways to calculate `aⁱ % m` on a computer. You should read the article.

However, as the [article also says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Software_implementations):

> Java's `java.math.BigInteger` class has a `modPow()` method to perform modular exponentiation

Combining all that to an efficient implementation in Java that doesn't use excessive amounts of memory:

```
static BigInteger calc(int n) {
    final BigInteger m = BigInteger.valueOf(10_000_000_000L);
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
        sum = sum.add(bi.modPow(bi, m));
    }
    return sum.mod(m);
}
```

Or the same using streams:

```
static BigInteger calc(int n) {
    final BigInteger m = BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(10);
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n).mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf).map(i -> i.modPow(i, m))
                    .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add).mod(m);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(calc(800)); // prints: 2831493860
```

Comment: I think you mean `sum % 10¹⁰` instead of `sum % 1¹⁰`

Comment: Huge thanks to all who replied, I didn't even consider modulo! *facepalm* I will also look into the other articles and methods mentioned. I know it said not to reply with "thanks," but I wasn't brought up not to show my appreciation.  So, thank you!!

Comment: @JulieCarres In addition to a comment, StackOverflow has two ways of showing thanks: 1) Click the up-arrow next to *all* answers that you find *useful*. That will award 10 reputation points to the answerer. 2) Click the check mark next to *one* of the answers, to *accept* that as the best full answer to your question. That will award 15 reputation points to the answerer and 2 points to you, and will show others that the question has been answered to your satisfaction. You can do both, thereby awarding a total of 25 points to a really good answer.

Comment: No need to use `BigInteger` at all.  The problem is feasible with just plain `long` variables.

Comment: @LuisColorado Sure, you just have to implement `modPow()` yourself. Or you could use the one already implemented for you in `BigInteger`.

Comment: implementing it is quite easy.  No more than 30 lines of code.  That way you are including the whole BigInteger class for only one function.  Bad spirit.

Comment: @LuisColorado *"including the whole BigInteger class"*? It's already included, in the Java Runtime Library. Are you also saying that we shouldn't use e.g. `ArrayList` in our code, because we can always build a custom implementation that only includes half the code? You're not making any sense. It is a dangerous waste of time to not use the built-in well-tested classes in production code, unless it is for pure academic exercise, and since this question doesn't preclude the use of `BigInteger`, this isn't it.

Comment: I mean the use of resources... It's already included, but what about if you want to use this software in an embedded device that lacks it (as result of the standard process of stripping the libraries to make enough place)  Badwasting resources is so common in actual times that people is beginning to think that's the correct way of thinking.  Why to make such a dependency based on that poor thinking?  building ArrayList should outcome with more resources as it is well optimized (believe me, I've read the code)  Anyway, do whatever you think is correct. FastPower is very cheap to implement.

Answer (score 0):

`BigInteger` would be suitable to work with these kinds of numbers.  It's quite frankly what it's designed for.

Do note that instances of `BigInteger` are *immutable* and any operations you do on one will give you back a *new* `BigInteger` instance.  You're going to want to store *some* of your results in variables.